# Accessing descendant controls in custom UIView using XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, xctest

the problem I am having is that I have reusable views / controls that contain text fields. These are xib files with a custom UI view class, such as the following:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
public class CustomControl: UIControl {

  @IBOutlet public weak var textField: UITextField?
  public var contentView: UIView?

  required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupViewFromNib()
  }

  override public init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViewFromNib()
  }

  override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupViewFromNib()
  }

  override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setupViewFromNib()
    contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
  }

  func setupViewFromNib() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    guard let textField = self.textField else { return }
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    contentView = view
  }

  func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let selfType = type(of: self)
    let nibName = String(describing: selfType)
    return Bundle(for: selfType)
        .loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)?
        .first as? UIView
  }
}
```

This custom view is being loaded into the Storyboards where they are to be used using the Storyboard Interface Builder.

The problem is that XCTest does not seem to model the descendants of these views, so when I am trying to write a test that involves typing text into the text field that is part of the custom view, the test bombs out with the error:

> Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.

Currently a work around appears to be to tap the keys on the keyboard instead of using the `typeText` method. However this is much slower (long pauses between key presses) and much more cumbersome test code wise.

The desired code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let view = app.otherElements["customView"]
let textField = view.textFields["textField"]
textField.tap()
textField.typeText("12345")
```

Using test recording we get something like:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let view = app.otherElements["customView"]
view.tap()
app.typeText("12345")
```

But running this test causes the aforementioned error.

The edited / working test becomes:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let view = app.otherElements["customView"]
// view appears as a leaf with no descendants
view.tap() 
app.keys["1"].tap()
app.keys["2"].tap()
app.keys["3"].tap()
app.keys["4"].tap()
app.keys["5"].tap()
```

I’m also not convinced this workaround will remain feasible if the custom view were to contain multiple controls, say perhaps for a date of birth control where I want more granular control over which field within the custom control I am using.

Is there a solution that allows me to access the fields within a custom view and potentially use the `typeText` method?

Comment: Do you have a sample project where this is reproducible?

Comment: Also is you need to make sure that accessibility is enabled on the textfield and not on the custom view itself

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. As advised by Titouan de Bailleul, the problem was that accessibility for the custom view had been enabled effectively hiding its descendant text fields.

[image: Accessibility enabled for UI component]

Thanks Titouan.

Comment: The solution is off GitHub now.